# Case when condition is Where clause SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to a use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause in SQL. I don't know how I to put it in.

For example:

```
select id , name = case when first_name = 'a' then 'NA' else null end
from MyTable 
where case when first_name = 'a' then 'NA' else null end is null
```

I want to show results when they are null. How can I do that please?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) A [mcve]

Comment: *Don't* use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` anyway; it isn't SARGable. Use `AND` and `OR`  logic. For this, it seems like you just want `WHERE first_name != 'a' OR first_name IS NULL` (Or in SQL Server 2022+ you could use `WHERE first_name IS DISTINCT FROM 'a'`).

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it returns a value. It's not a flow control statement. What you tried to write would return either a string or null. What would this be compared against? What you tried is the equivalent of `WHERE 'NA'` or `WHERE NULL`

Comment: Of course, using said `WHERE` clause (in my comment above) renders your `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` somewhat pointless; it would always return `NULL` as the no rows where the condition `first_name = 'a'` is true would be returned; meaning you might as well change the `SELECT` to `SELECT id, NULL`.

Comment: There is no actual syntax error there. RE "What would this be compared against" - the comparison is using `is null` - it isn't trying to use it as a flow control statement. But instead of telling us your desired solution "use a CASE expression in the WHERE clause" tell us the actual problem.

Comment: I think the "where" you are trying might not produce the result you are after, even it you get it working. It would be best to show us some sample data and also show us what you want to achieve with that data, so we can understand what you really want

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your query here is query that should work.

```
SELECT 
    [id] 
    ,CASE [first_name] WHEN 'a' THEN 'NA' ELSE NULL END AS 'name' 
FROM [MyTabl] 
WHERE 1 = CASE [first_name] WHEN 'a' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

You can use the case to return a string or numeric and then just say where equal to that value. Warning this can be quite slow and it is better to use an where statement.
This would be better as a select statement :

```
SELECT 
    [id] 
    ,CASE [first_name] WHEN 'a' THEN 'NA' ELSE NULL END AS 'name' 
FROM [MyTabl] 
WHERE [first_name] <> 'a'
```

Alternative query :

```
SELECT 
    [id] 
    ,CASE [first_name] WHEN 'a' THEN 'NA' ELSE NULL END AS 'name' 
FROM [MyTabl] 
WHERE [id] NOT IN ( SELECT [id] WHERE [first_name] = 'a' )
```

Comment: *If* `first_name` is `NULL`able, the second query will also not return those rows. For the first, as i mentioned, such a query won't be SARGable, so for a large dataset performance could be quite poor.